# support level for w3c specifications for different broswers

Tags: google-chrome, browser, internet-explorer, safari

Where can I find information on the level of browser support, for each browser, for w3c HTML5/CSS3 specification.

I found a [Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(HTML5)#Elements) which provides some info on this, but the comparison charts include the previous layout engines of Chrome and Opera, not the current ones.

Anyone know good places to look for this?

Comment: Be sure to check out PPK's quirksmode.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a nice visual comparison of browsers' support, try http://html5readiness.com/.
For more statistics, refer to [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/).